# How to determine if an element exists in a Perl 6 array

Tags: arrays, list, containers, raku

I thought there would have been a simple answer for this somewhere on the internet but it seems like I'm having trouble finding a solution. I'm first of all wondering if there's a simple method or function for this:

e.g. `~~` or `array.contains()` from Perl 5

It would also be nice to know how many different ways of achieving this result there are in Perl 6 as some might be better than others given the situation of the problem.

Comment: You can use `$elem ~~ any @array`. `any` creates a Junction of the elements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
my @a = <foo bar buzz>;
say so 'bar' ∈ @a;
say so @a ∋ 'buzz';
# OUTPUT«True␤True␤»
```

As documented in http://doc.perl6.org/language/setbagmix and defined in https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/src/core/set_operators.pm .

I believe that `Set` checks for equivalence, if you need identity you will have to loop over the array and `===` it.

You could turn the `Array` into a `Set` and use subscripts.

```
say @a.Set{'bar'};
# OUTPUT«True␤»
say @a.Set<bar buzz>;
# OUTPUT«(True True)␤»
```

Comment: Note that there are huge performance consequences for using an array as a set, especially when doing so repeatedly.  In that case, you really need to do something like `my $s = @a.Set;` outside the loop, and do `$elem ∈ $s` in the loop.

Answer (score 11):

Another way to do this, is:

```perl
my @a = <foo bar buzz>;
if 'bar' eq any(@a) {
    say "yes";
}
# OUTPUT«yes␤»
```

Answer (score 5):

[Sub first documentation.](http://doc.perl6.org/routine/first) `sub first` returns the matching element or `Nil`. `Nil` is a falsey value meaning you can use the result in a `Bool` context to determine if the array contains matching element.

```
my @a = 'A'..'Z';
say 'We got it' if @a.first('Z');
say 'We didn\'t get it' if !@a.first(1);
```

There are several adverbs to `sub first` which change the results. For instance to return the index instead of the element it is possible use the `:k` adverb. In this example we also topicalize the result for use within the `if` statement:

```
my @a = 'A'..'Z';
if @a.first('Q', :k) -> $index {
    say $index;
}
```